# Intel IPP ippsFree() crashes

Tags: c++, intel-ipp

I tried following code to check how fast the Intel IPP is for resizing / converting images, but it keeps on crashing at ippsFree(pSpec) at the end, and I cannot figure out, why.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <memory>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "ipp.h"

int main(...) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int channels = 2;
    IppiResizeYUV422Spec* pSpec;
    IppiSize dstSize, srcSize;
    IppiPoint dstOffset = { 0, 0 };
    srcSize.width = width;
    srcSize.height = height;
    dstSize.width = 2 * width;
    dstSize.height = 2 * height;
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> sourceData;
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> destinationData;
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> destinationDataRGB;
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> workBuffer;

    sourceData.reset(new unsigned char[srcSize.width * srcSize.height * channels]);
    destinationData.reset(new unsigned char[dstSize.width * dstSize.height * channels]);
    destinationDataRGB.reset(new unsigned char[dstSize.width * dstSize.height * 3]);
    workBuffer.reset(new unsigned char[dstSize.width * dstSize.height * channels]);

    memset(sourceData.get(), 0, srcSize.width * srcSize.height * channels);
    memset(destinationData.get(), 0, dstSize.width * dstSize.height * channels);
    memset(workBuffer.get(), 0, dstSize.width * dstSize.height * channels);

    IppStatus error;
    int specSize = 0, initSize = 0, buffSize = 0;
    error = ippiResizeGetSize_8u(srcSize, dstSize, IppiInterpolationType::ippNearest, 0, &specSize, &initSize);

    pSpec = (IppiResizeYUV422Spec*) ippsMalloc_8u(specSize);
    error = ippiResizeYUV422NearestInit(srcSize, dstSize, pSpec);

    IppiRect srcRoi = { 0, 0, srcSize.width, srcSize.height };

    int64_t timerIPP9 = 0;
    LARGE_INTEGER start, end;
    LARGE_INTEGER tps;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&tps);

    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < 100; ++index) {
        for (unsigned int imageIdx = 0; imageIdx < srcSize.width * srcSize.height * channels; ++imageIdx) {
            sourceData.get()[imageIdx] = (rand() & 0xFF);
        }

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
        error = ippiResizeYUV422Nearest_8u_C2R(
            sourceData.get(),
            srcSize.width * channels,
            destinationData.get(),
            dstSize.width * channels,
            dstOffset,
            dstSize,
            pSpec,
            workBuffer.get());
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

        timerIPP9 += end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart;

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
        ippiYCbCr422ToRGB_8u_C2C3R(destinationData.get(), dstSize.width * channels, destinationDataRGB.get(), dstSize.width * 3, dstSize);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

        timerIPP9 += end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart;
        printf("Test: %d, time: %d ms\r", index, timerIPP9 * 1000 / tps.QuadPart);
    }

    ippsFree(pSpec);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Time taken: %d ms\n", timerIPP9 * 1000 / tps.QuadPart);
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am just piping random data into the converter, but it should be able to deal with the noise (as it still is a valid image).

Comment: I am using the latest Intel IPP 2017.1.143

Comment: Have you tried freeing right after allocation? And it doesn't look like you're checking error responses. (Disclaimer: I've never used Intel IPP)

Comment: I've never used Intel IPP either. Could the problem be that you somehow write outside the `pSpec` buffer, which it then notices when calling `ippsFree`?

Comment: I allocate the pSpec with around 9000 bytes, and later the runtime says the heap is 2444 bytes, so something is going wrong, I just don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved the puzzle...

All you need to do is replacing the following like of code:

```
error = ippiResizeGetSize_8u(srcSize, dstSize, IppiInterpolationType::ippNearest, 0, &specSize, &initSize);
```

With the following one:

```
error = ippiResizeYUV422GetSize(srcSize, dstSize, IppiInterpolationType::ippNearest, 0, &specSize, &initSize);
```

According to IPP documentation:

> Description 
>   This function initializes the IppiResizeYUV422Spec structure for the resize algorithm with the nearest neighbor interpolation method.
>   To calculate the size of the spec structure object, call the ippiResizeYUV422GetSize function.

See: http://hpc.ipp.ac.cn/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/documentation_2016/en/ipp/common/ipp_manual/GUID-15B51AB0-7F73-4E13-AC81-753259CE0E2C.htm

When executing `ippiResizeYUV422GetSize`, value of `specSize` equals `11776`.
When executing `ippiResizeGetSize_8u`, value of `specSize` equals `9240`.
The smaller allocated size results corrupted heap.